# PDF won't display in browser window

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, ashx

I am using a handler to get and display a PDF in the browser window using the code below:

```
byte[] byt = RetrieveDocument(int.Parse(context.Request.Params["id"]), context.Request.Params["title"]);
string file = WriteDocumentFilePDF(byt);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", byt.Length.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=programdetails.pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(byt);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

The function WriteDocumentFilePDF successfully writes the PDF to the temp directory. I have the above code working correctly in a different application. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

When debugging issues like this, I find that Fiddler is an invaluable tool; many many times it has saved me from simple mistakes. Also, this site http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/what-is-an-ashx-file-handler-or-web-handler/ gives an example of doing the same thing but with a GIF image. The difference between your example and his seems to be the use of Response.WriteFile() rather than the direct write to the Response using BinaryWrite().

I would perform a Response.ClearHeaders() before I set the content-type and I would remove the call to Response.End().

Answer (score 0):

Does it make a difference if you pass the `byte[]` to `memorystream` first?  So something like

```
byte[] byt = RetrieveDocument(int.Parse(context.Request.Params["id"]), context.Request.Params["title"]);
string file = WriteDocumentFilePDF(byt);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byt);
```

And then add your headers

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";    
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;  filename=programdetails.pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```